# Приоритет правил при оформлении прямой речи в диалогах

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, диалог

Мне известно о нескольких противоречивых правилах оформления прямой речи. В диалоге, где прямая речь каждого лица начинается с новой строки, нужно использовать тире вместо кавычек. В то же время дополнительное сказуемое снова превращает тире в кавычки. Каков приоритет этих правил и как следует оформить прямую речь в этих примерах:

1. Тут все просто и ясно - используем тире:

> – Один, – сказал А. – Два!

2. Вот тут наступает момент, когда правила нужно приоритизировать. Оформлять по правилу прямой речи с новой строки с тире, или по правилу дополнительного сказуемого с кавычками:

> – Три, – сказал Б и спросил. – Четыре?

или

> "Три," – сказал Б и спросил: "Четыре?"

3. Теперь добавим ещё одну простую ремарку диалога с тире для связи:

> – Пять, – предложил В. – Шесть.

4. А после неё пойдёт ремарка в другой структуре. Что нужно применить тут: тире или кавычки?

> Г вошел в помещение и обратился ко всем: "Семь, восемь".

5. Итак, совместим всё это в сплошной текст для простоты понимания:

> – Один, – сказал А. – Два!
>
> – Три, – сказал Б и спросил. – Четыре?
>
> "Три," – сказал Б и спросил: "Четыре?"
>
> – Пять, – предложил В. – Шесть.
>
> Г вошел в помещение и обратился ко всем: "Семь, восемь".

Требуется определить, использовать ли строку 2 или 3 и какие знаки использовать в строке 5: двоеточие с кавычками или тире без кавычек.

Comment: «Использовать ли строку 2 или 3»? Если только в этом вопрос, то к чему весь остальной текст? (К п. 5 претензий быть не может, ибо в ней всё нормально, а от добра добра не ищут.)

Comment: Можете искромсать, как Вам угодно. Всё равно на этом ресурсе задающий вопрос не имеет никаких прав и относятся к нему, как мусору.

Comment: И я не представляю ресурс, и Вы — не представитель задающих вопросы. Стену в сообществе никто не строил и не собирается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По строке 2 есть такие правила:

Розенталь

> Если в словах автора, находящихся внутри прямой речи, имеются два
>   глагола со значением высказывания, из которых один относится к первой
>   части прямой речи, а другой — ко второй, то после слов автора ставятся
>   двоеточие и тире, причем первое слово второй части пишется с прописной
>   буквы:
>
> «Я тебя не спрашиваю, — строго ***сказал*** офицер и снова ***спросил***: —
>   Старуха, отвечай?» (М. Г.); «Покорно благодарю, — отозвался Мешков,
>   смиренно снял картузик, но сразу опять надел и поклонился, добавив
>   торопливо: — Спасибо вам большое, товарищи» (Фед.).

Лопатин:

> Если слова автора распадаются по смыслу на две части, которые относятся к разным частям прямой речи, то при соблюдении других
>   условий после слов автора ставятся двоеточие и тире: «Эхма... —
>   безнадежно ***вздохнул*** Гаврила в ответ на суровое приказание и горько
>   ***добавил***: — Судьбина моя пропащая!» (М. Г.); «Не трогай мундир! —
>   ***приказал*** Лермонтов и ***добавил***, ничуть не сердясь, а даже с некоторым
>   любопытством: — Станешь ты меня слушать или нет?» (Пауст.); «Вы
>   чувствовали когда-нибудь на руках запах меди? — ***спросил*** неожиданно
>   гравер и, не дожидаясь ответа, поморщился и ***продолжал:*** — Ядовитый,
>   омерзительный» (Пауст.).

***Стало быть, надо так:***

> – Один, – сказал А. – Два!
>
> – Три, – сказал Б и спросил: – Четыре?

---

По строке 5, честно сказать, о приоритизации я не слышал. Тут можно так оформить:

> – Один, – сказал А. – Два!
>
> – Три, – сказал Б и спросил: – Четыре?
>
> – Пять, – предложил В. – Шесть.
>
> Г вошел в помещение и обратился ко всем:
>
> — Семь, восемь.

Или так:

> – Один, – сказал А. – Два!
>
> – Три, – сказал Б и спросил: – Четыре?
>
> – Пять, – предложил В. – Шесть.
>
> Г вошел в помещение и обратился ко всем: "Семь, восемь".

Но первый вариант явно предпочтительнее. Для "живых" реплик, обращённых "в прямом эфире" к собеседнику чаще всего используется абзац с тире. Нет особого смысла последнюю реплику диалога оформлять в строку и делать кавычной. Однако сказать, что второй вариант неправильный, нельзя, конечно. Но он точно менее предпочтителен.

Comment: Прекрасный анализ. А можно дополнительный вопрос? Если речь автора после прямой состоит больше, чем из 1го предложения, то последующие нужно выделять в отдельный параграф или нет? Например: `- Раз, - сказал А. Далее он сделал два и три. На это Б ответил:` Второе предложение следует продолжать в том же параграфе, или выделить в новый?